How does DPDK guarantee fixed/pinned physical address for huge pages
According to this DPDK blog, physical addresses of huge pages are "pinned":

Whenever a memory area is made available for DPDK to use, DPDK figures out its physical address by asking the kernel at that time. Since DPDK uses pinned memory, generally in the form of huge pages, the physical address of the underlying memory area is not expected to change, so the hardware can rely on those physical addresses to be valid at all times, even if the memory itself is not used for some time. DPDK then uses these physical addresses when preparing I/O transactions to be done by the hardware, and configures the hardware in such a way that the hardware is allowed to initiate DMA transactions itself. This allows DPDK to avoid needless overhead and to perform I/O entirely from user space.

What I am sure about is that Linux guarantees huge pages are not swapped (written here):

Pages that are used as huge pages are reserved inside the kernel and cannot
be used for other purposes.  Huge pages cannot be swapped out under
memory pressure.

According to the man pages, mlock() guarantees preventing memory from being paged to the swap area, but it does not mention pinning physical memory.
There must be some method that DPDK uses to fix the physical address of huge pages. What is that method and how does it work?

A hugepage is a physical object.  Its physical address cannot change, only its virtual address.  See https://kerneltalks.com/services/what-is-huge-pages-in-linux/
